# Autoclose brackets/parentheses inside a string in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, intellij-15, auto-close

Recently I have been using PyCharm Community Edition solely for python development and I am really pleased with the software!

But while the auto closing of parentheses and tags works in regular code, it doesn't work when I try to do it inside a string.
I can't find a setting that will allow this.

What I mean is this:

```
print('(')
```

It does not auto close the parenthesis inside the string.

-I went to the smart keys section of the editor settings but to no avail.

-I also tried to uncheck all the intentions in the Python editor but again, nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think so the feature exists as there is no use for autocompleting parenthesis functionality in string except for very few situations, the feature is used for coding in a widespread manner i.e. for functions, classes, etc. Refer this for additional information: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/completing-punctuation.html#enable-adding-closing-braces